# Update Symfony bundle with composer ignoring the minimum-stability setting

Tags: paypal, composer-php, symfony, payum

I installed the payum/payum-bundle with composer (using the PHP Storm Plugin).
I couldn't install a version newer to 2.0.1 because the newer version seems not to be marked as stable (minimum-stability in composer.lock is "stable").
I too installed the payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp bundle to add paypay express support.
I set everything up, created a controller to test it and ended up getting the error

```
Attempted to load trait "GatewayAwareTrait" from namespace "Payum\Core".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

According to this (closed) issue the problem seems to be that payum/core is at version 1.2.8 but should be at least 1.3

https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/367

Obviously the payum/bundle installation in version 2.0.1 installed the core-part with 1.2.8.
Now... How can I force composer to update the payum/core to at least 1.3?

What I need to do is either tell composer to ignore the minimum-stability for this single bundle or to set the minimum-stability to something less then stable (which I assume not being the best idea especialy when not permanently following all dev branches of all used packages) and a hint on how then to update the payum/core part.

Any hints are very wellcome - I am stuck here...

Comment: What's in you composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong, the version 2.1.0 of payum/payum-bundle is marked as stable.

In order to find out why you don't install it, we need your content of `composer.json`.

Did you run `composer update` in order to try to update to the latest packages of everything?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.3.0 Payum require a virtual package [http client](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/composer.json#L45). You must add one of its implementations as a package, after that composer will allow you to upgrade payum.

The doc [suggest you to install](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Core/Resources/docs/get-it-started.md) php-http/guzzle6-adapter but you can choose any other implementations of the client.

Do

```
php composer.phar update payum/core php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```